# Unhandled exception at 0x012351CF in HW3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have done an implementation of a (ADT) binary shearch tree, i had to do a function which count the number of Parents that thire sons have a difference which is less then five. the program works, only this functon fails.

at the 'return' (recursive) i got a break point.

```
int difference(BSTNode *root, comperFunc cmpFn, comperFunc lesserThenFive)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (root)
    {
        count = 0;
        if (root->Left && root->Right)
        {
            //if root->Right > root->Left
            if (cmpFn(root->Right->key, root->Left->key) == 1)
            {
                if (lesserThenFive(root->Right->key, root->Left->key))
                     count = 1;  
            }
            //if root->Right < root->Left
            if (cmpFn(root->Right->key, root->Left->key) == -1)
            {
                if (lesserThenFive(root->Left->key, root->Right->key))
                    count = 1;    
            }
       }
   }
   return difference(root->Left, cmpFn, lesserThenFive) + difference(root- >Right, cmpFn, lesserThenFive) + count;//here is the break point
```

}

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: `return difference(root->Left,...` : If `root` is `NULL`, `NULL` dereference will occur

Comment: @Lundin Turns out it wasn't impossible to tell :-)

Comment: @JeremyP Right. One might find out if one can actually be bothered to read questions with code taken away from any form of context. The bug might as well have been on the caller side.

Comment: i have double chacked with outher functions and it is not a problem from the caller side...

Comment: As @JeremyP and BLUEPIXY said.  The problem is that you have no return except for the recursive return. There are at least two problems with that: 1) you'll dereference a null pointer at one of the calls (this is the crash you see), and 2) when should the recursion stop even if the null dereference didn't crash the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `return` statement you will dereference a null pointer, if you enter `difference` and `root` is null.

That return needs to be inside the `if` bock and you need to return some sutable value in the `else` part.

To expand a bit. Your algorithm recursivley calls `difference` with the left and right nodes of the current `root` but eventually one of `root->left` or `root->right` is going to be `NULL`. Your return statement will then, effectively try to call `difference` with the left or right member of NULL e.g. `NULL->left`. This will seg fault on any modern operating system.

Comment: the dereference is a speeling mistake... it is difference

Comment: When I say "dereference" it is not talking about your spelling mistake but accessing the memory pointed at by `root`. If you do `*root` in C, you are dereferencing `root`. `root->left` is shorthand for `(*root).left`